# C++ Structure returning true, but why?

Tags: c++, structure, binary-search-tree

Doing some coursework and I need to make a binary search tree. Piece of cake, should be fun. 
Since C++ doesn't feature a dictionary I've decided to make one using a BST.
I found some sample code online to give me a brief idea as to how they're put together and it's all relatively simple but being new to C++ and having come from a C# environment, one thing has thrown me into confusion and that is 'c'. I don't understand why 'c' is returning true in the while loop or why changing the data in left or right would affect this outcome.

```
node* t = new node;
node* parent;

t->data;
t->left  = NULL;
t->right = NULL;
parent   = NULL;

...

    node* c;
    c = root;

    while (c)
    {
        parent = c;

        if(t->data > c->data)
        {
            c = c->right;
        }
        else //else it's assigned left
        {
            c = c->left;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++, a pointer is considered false if it's null, and true otherwise. This while loop keeps walking down the tree until `c` becomes a null pointer.

Also, C++ *does* have dictionaries. Check out `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. Thank you very much. I read about std::map earlier but I guess it slipped my mind but oh well, no harm in reinventing the wheel.